# How to output colab ipynb to pdf/epub with bookmarks?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I created some ipynb in google colab, which has nice bookmarks support as below, [image]

I want to know how to create pdf/epub format books with these bookmarks, they are actually h1, h2 tag for markdown.

```
# h1 title
## h2 title
```

I try to dowload the ipynb format and use jupyter nbconvert, but the output pdf is very ugly without any bookmark.

So my question is, **how to output my ipynb to pdf with `# head` title as sorted bookmarks**?

Thanks for any advice in advance.